# Will the git installation creates the .gitconfig file in the user's home directory?

Tags: git, github, version-control

When exactly .gitconfig is created?
Is it during the git installation or after executing the `git config --global` command?

Answer (score 1):

This file is created after your first configuration entry. If you have a fresh install of git and you run `git config --global -l` it will tell you it cannot find the current configuration. After you configure your first global item, the file will exist.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, it is when you run `git config --global`.